# Installed Google app engine in Eclipse Kepler and toolbar not updated

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have installed google app engine for Eclipse Kelper and restarted however nothing has changed in Eclipse. I don't have the option to make a new web application. I checked and Eclipse says the app engine is installed.

```
Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.15   1.9.15  com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r43 com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group Google, Inc.
Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3   3.8.0.v201410302155-rel-r43 com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e43.feature.feature.group  Google, Inc.
Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.6.0    2.6.0   com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group  Google, Inc.
GWT Designer Core   3.1.3.r43x201405021502  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
GWT Designer Editor 3.1.3.r43x201405021509  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.
GWT Designer GPE    3.1.3.r43x201405021554  com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.gpe.feature.feature.group   Google, Inc.
```

Comment: There is a solution in another related question that requires you to reinstall the app engine after opening Eclipse with administrator privileges, which I tried but made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, if you right click "new -> other...google", then "web application project" is available under "web services". Strange that the option doesn't appear under File but it works...

Comment: Hii Jerry, I also got this problem, but cannot find any related menu for google app enginer, includes your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you asking?